# Can someone please explain the function as im not sure of the purpose of using index

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  

    <h1>JavaScript Task 3- Traffic Light Sequence </h1> 

  <img id="light" src="./assets/red.png" height="205" width="95">
  <button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>  
  <script> 
    var colours = ["./assets/red.png","./assets/red_and_amber.png", "./assets/green.png","./assets/amber.png" ];
    var index = 0;
    function changeLights() {
      index = index + 1;      
      if (index == colours.length) 
        index = 0;      
      var image = document.getElementById('light');     
      image.src = colours[index]; 
    } 
  </script>  
</body> 
</html>
```

> > > this code is to show a traffic light sequence. First red, then red and amber, then green, then back to amber, and then back to red. I'm unsure of what the function exactly does line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Index is the number to use with colours array.
Ex:`colours[0]` is the first colour in the array;
Then the index +=1,now index==1;
The second time:
`colours[1]` is the second,etc

Answer (score 0):

> I'm unsure of what the function exactly does line by line.

Here is a line-by-line explanation:

```
var colours = [
    "./assets/red.png",
    "./assets/red_and_amber.png",
    "./assets/green.png",
    "./assets/amber.png"
];
```

Sets up an array called `colours`, containing 4 values.

```
var index = 0;
```

Sets up a variable called `index`.

```
function changeLights() {
```

Sets up a function called `changeLights`.

```
  index = index + 1;
```

Increases the value of `index` by `1`.

```
  if (index === colours.length) {
```

Checks if the value of `index` is equal to the number of values in the `colours` array.

```
  index = 0;
```

Resets `index` to `0`.

```
  var image = document.getElementById('light');
```

Finds `<img id="light" ... />` in the markup and assigns it to a variable called `image`.

```
  image.src = colours[index];
```

Rests the `src` value of `image` to the `index`-th value of the `colours` array.

Comment: Thanks appreciate this.